# Unauthorized error when using SendListen shared access key to GetConsumerGroupAsync

Tags: azure-eventhub

We started observing following error from yesterday while we are trying to access Consumer Group using SendListen Key. It is throwing Unauthorized error. If I use RootManagerSharedAccessKey, this works fine.

```
var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://*****.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SendListen;SharedAccessKey=****";
        var ns = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        var result= ns.GetConsumerGroupAsync("**", "**").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Exception:
'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. TrackingId:e2993246-9253-4cb7-ab54-2a9b32abfec7, SystemTracker:***.windows.net:dataoffload/ConsumerGroups/**, Timestamp:8/11/2017 12:33:46 AM'

Any recent changes in EventHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side. Here is my test, you could refer to it.

**SETTING > Shared access policies**

[image]

**Code snippet:**

```
var connString = "Endpoint=sb://{my-hubname}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SendListen;SharedAccessKey=aTu3sxJ1TMLXDWN6ErkHp28aVL/Fstfa49MkuibbQ7A=";
var ns = Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connString);
var result = ns.GetConsumerGroupAsync("myhub01", "$Default").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Upon the settings, I could retrieve the description of my consumer group. Also, for the single **Listen** policy, it could work as well. Based on your error, I would recommend you checking your `CONNECTION STRING`. Also, you could leverage fiddler to collect the network traces for details.